# Learning python - looking to display results loaded from a DB into a gui

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning python and Tkinter for a specific project. I have a little programing background, but its been a long while.

I am able to load my DB into an array without trouble. I am struggling to find code examples to help me with the GUI portion.

What I am trying to do is open a GUI with Tkinter and have an input field to search an SQL database.
--> input [select * from db where name like '%bob%'] [ go ]
on button press [go], load results from the SQL query (which is first red into an array)

I am having trouble figuring out how to approach this.

```
def main():
    frame = Tk()
    frame.geometry("480x360")

    ##////////////////////////////
    display = Label(frame, text="")
    display.grid(row=5, column=1)
    ##////////////////////////////
  
    def go():
        try:
            conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=WINx;DATABASE=dbx;Trusted_connection=yes')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Customer")
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                display.configure(text=row)
                print(row)  ## ONLY prints the last row in DB
            conn.close()
        except:
            display.configure(text="FAILURE")

    Button(frame, text="10p", command=lambda: go().grid(row=3, column=1)

    frame.mainloop()

main()
```

Any good advice for solving this problem?
My end goal is to have a user "select" a database field and do something with that selection. But I'm not there yet.

Comment: Do you mean that you can get only the last record printed in the console? Or only the last record shown in the GUI label?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a biased answer, but try to work through the tutorial at tkdocs.com to get yourself familiar with Tkinter. Even from the initial examples you'll get a feel for how to structure your application.

Comment: Thank you. I have been as well. There is a lot to learn and I do pretty good if I have some working code to manipulate rather than guess at syntax.